# How to customize font and color of an element in OpenERP 6.0

Tags: css, fonts, colors, label, openerp-6

I searched all topic but I can't find way to optimize font and color of a label in OpenERP 6.0. I found this `<tree string="Imported Bank Statements Files" colors="red:state=='error';blue:state=='unfinished'">` in source code but it is only for tree (100% result in my source code is tree). Does anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Web Developer](https://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) plugin.

 Once you hover on the place where you want edit, you can get a details (such as Script Location & ect..)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately but that's no that I want. I am using OpenERP client desktop application, not web.